# Testing security in Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to test `@WebMvcTest` with custom security settings defined in  `SecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").antMatchers("/**").permitAll().and().formLogin();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Test class is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ExampleController.class)
public class ExampleControllerMockMVCTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void indexTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("index"));
    }

    @Test
    public void adminTestWithoutAuthentication() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/admin"))
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection()); //login form redirect
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="example", password="password", roles={"ANONYMOUS"})
    public void adminTestWithBadAuthentication() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/admin"))
        .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="user", password="password", roles={"ADMIN"})
    public void adminTestWithAuthentication() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/admin"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("admin"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeExists("name"))
        .andExpect(model().attribute("name", is("user")));
    }
}
```

Tests fail because they are using the default security settings of Spring Boot.

I can fix this using `@SpringBootTest` + `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`, but it would be interesting to test without running all auto-configuration.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ExampleControllerSpringBootTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    // tests
}
```

Is there any way that `@WebMvcTest` can use settings defined in `SecurityConfig` class?

Comment: just add this to the "application.properties" (in "src/main/resources"): security.user.password=password (and choose your own password)

Comment: Thanks but don´t fix it... still using the default security settings but forcing password to "password". I'm just securing "/admin*" URIs using role "ADMIN", default security configuration protects all URIs using role "USER".

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. I wasn't aware of default security protecting all URIs with `USER`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`WebMvcTest` is only going to load your controller and nothing else (that's why we call that slicing). We can't figure out which part of your configuration you want and which one you don't. If the security config isn't on your main `@SpringBootApplication` you'll have to import it explicitly. Otherwise, Spring Boot is going to enable default security settings.

If you're using something like OAuth, that's a good thing though because you really don't want to start using that for a mock test. What happens if you add `@Import(SecurityConfig.class)` to your test?

Comment: FYI: there is also a related discussion in the Spring Boot issue tracker: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6514