# Why spring test is fail, does not work @MockBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

I try to create my first the test for a simple spring-boot controller but I get `Handler: Type = null`. In browser code is work but a test fails. My App use spring-security. Please help me fix it an issue and understand my mistake. Thank You.

This is controller:

```
private final ItemService service;

@GetMapping("/get_all_items")
public String getAllItems(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("items", service.getAll());
    return "all_items";
}
```

This is a test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ItemController.class)
public class ItemControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private ItemService itemService;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = "user")//mock security.
    public void whenGetAllItemsThenControllerReturnAllItems() throws Exception {
        given(
            itemService.getAll()
        ).willReturn(
                new ArrayList<Item>()
        );

        mvc.perform(
            get("/get_all_items").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        ).andExpect(
                status().isOk()
        );
    }
}
```

This is result log:

> MockHttpServletRequest:
>         HTTP Method = GET
>         Request URI = /get_all_items
>          Parameters = {}
>             Headers = {Accept=[text/html]}
>
> Handler:
>                Type = null
>
> Async:
>       Async started = false
>        Async result = null
>
> Resolved Exception:
>                Type = null
>
> ModelAndView:
>           View name = null
>                View = null
>               Model = null
>
> FlashMap:
>          Attributes = null
>
> MockHttpServletResponse:
>              Status = 403
>       Error message = Access is denied
>             Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store,
>   max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0],
>   X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ;
>   includeSubDomains]}
>        Content type = null
>                Body = 
>       Forwarded URL = null    Redirected URL = null
>             Cookies = []
>
> java.lang.AssertionError: Status  Expected :200 Actual   :403

Comment: Have you tried `@MockMvc`? Is there some changes?

Comment: The error is right there. `: Status = 403 Error message = Access is denied Header`. You need to provide security creds, or disable it for the unit-testing.

Comment: @Darren Forsythe Yes but I use `@WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = "user")` it's not enough? How to implement provide security creds? I think my @WithMockUser solve.

Comment: @Reborn I try to replace `@Autowired` to `@MockMvc` after You're a comment but my IDE get the warning message about constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially a duplicate question that has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676144/388980

The solution is to *import* the `@Configuration` class for your Spring Security configuration in addition to declaring `@WebMvcTest(ItemController.class)` like this `@Import(SecurityConfig.class)` (assuming your custom configuration for Spring Security is in a class named `SecurityConfig`).

You might also find the discussion in Spring Boot's issue tracker helpful as well: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6514

The other option is to *disable* Spring Security as explained here: [Disable security for unit tests with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169720/disable-security-for-unit-tests-with-spring-boot/35192495)

Comment: my mistake  @WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = "user") ->@WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = "USER") need convert role "user" too CAPSLOOK. And all ok.