# How to .getPrincipal() in spring-boot test of POST method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a POST method which for sends `Item`. Each Item contains the id of User which author. And for get author id I use :`(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();` 
But in test, this does not work due to result :

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to ru.pravvich.domain.User`

POST method:

```
@PostMapping("/get_all_items/add_item_page/add_item")
public String addItem(@RequestParam(value = "description") final String description) {

    final User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .getAuthentication()
            .getPrincipal();

    final Item item = new Item();
    item.setDescription(description);
    item.setAuthorId(user.getId());
    service.add(item);
    return "redirect:/get_all_items";
}
```

And test:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = "USER")
public void whenPostThenAdd() throws Exception {

    Item item = new Item();
    item.setDescription("test");

    mvc.perform(
            post("/get_all_items/add_item_page/add_item")
                    .param("description", "test")
    ).andExpect(
            status().is3xxRedirection()
    );

    verify(itemService, times(1)).add(item);
}
```

Why `ClassCastException` does not throw then I send data from the browser form? How fix this issue?

Thank You.

**UPDATE:**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
            if (user == null) user = new User();
            return user;
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why spring test is fail, does not work @MockBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905591/why-spring-test-is-fail-does-not-work-mockbean)

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `@WithUserDetails`? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withuserdetails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@WithMockUser` helps you to inject a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` object and perform the test, but in this case you need a custom user object `ru.pravvich.domain.User`.

Why it works with browser form? it is because the principal comes from your authentication process, for example if you have your own `UserDetailsService` in order to return your custom `ru.pravvich.domain.User`, this process happens in a normal case scenario when you perform authetnication by the web form, but in a test case scenario it doesn't happens at least you configure the test case and inform about your custom implementation.  Let's see an example:

A Custom user class that extends from User (**update here**)

```
   //MySpring user is just a class that extends from 
   //org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
   //org...security....User implements UserDetailsService that is the 
   //the reason why I can return this class from loadUserByUsername method, you will see it later
   //it helps me to wrap my own User definition
   public class MySpringUser  extends User {

    //this is my own user definition, where all my custom fields are defined
    private MyUser user;

    //the constructor expect for myUser and then I call the super
    //constructor to fill the basic fields that are mandatory for spring 
    //security in order to perform the authentication process
    public MySpringUser(MyUser myUser, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(myUser.getUsername(), myUser.getPassword(), myUser.isEnabled()
                , true, true, true, authorities);

        this.setUser(myUser);
    }

    public MyUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(MyUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    //this is an example of how to get custom fields a custom id for example
    public Long getId(){
        return this.getUser().getId();
    }
}
```

A Custom UserDetails Service (**update here**)

```
@Service
public class MyUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    MyUserRepository myUserRepository;

    //Principal
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        //Here I get the User that I defined for my own domain structure
        MyUser myUser = myUserRepository.findFirstByUsername(s);

        //Here I return a new User object, in this case MySpringUser is
        //just a class that  extends from User class, its constructor 
        //receive myUser object as parameter in order to get my own custom fields later   
        return new MySpringUser(myUser,AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ADMIN"));

    }
}
```

Finally the test case using `@WithUserDetails` to inform that the test should call the `loadUserByUsername` method that is implemented by the custom `UserDetailsService`, in that case you are free to cast the principal to your custom user object.

```
    @Test
    @WithUserDetails( "myUserNameOnDatabase")
    public void contextLoads() {
        try {
            mockMvc.perform(get("/stores")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This is how cast is performed in the controller, just like yours

```
  @RequestMapping("/stores")
    public List<Store> getStores(Principal principal){

        MySpringUser activeUser = (MySpringUser) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
        System.out.println(activeUser.getUsername());

        return storeRepository.findByMyUserId();

    }
```

(**Update here**) I also uploaded a full example to my git repo, you can download it and try it in order to give you a more clear view, of course this is just one option, there are others, for example instead of extends spring User class you can create your own class that implements the `UserDetails` interface, the alternative will depends on your needs.

Hope this alternative help you.

[My git Repo example of how use `@WithUserDetails`](https://github.com/faustocdiaz/spring-security-spel-sample)

Comment: Thank You. I have an issue with understanding `loadUserByUsername(String s)` may be You might rewrite without lambda? And I have one more question: is there the path to a solution without `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`? My auth system crash then I use `security...User` I update the question to and my UserServiece version. May be it give more information about the situation. Thank You one more time.

Comment: Yes! You are great! It's work. Git repo answer on all questions. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security's `@WithMockUser` populates the security context with a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` object, which is why you're encountering this exception.  The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser) is pretty clear about this:

> The principal on the Authentication is Spring Security’s User object

One possible solution to your `ClassCastException` is to simply reuse Spring's `User` class and use `getUsername()` to return the author ID, or if you must customer the `User` object, find another way to populate the security context for your tests.