# testing spring security with @secured always returns 200

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

[@Import solves my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675020/testing-security-in-spring-boot-1-4)

========================

I am using Spring security @Secured at controller and it works fine when I test it in the browser, logging in with different users with different roles can see / cannot see different url (200 vs 403). but it fails at junit. it already returns 200 no matter what the role is. here is my setting.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
class UserController {

@GetMapping("/admin")
@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
ResponseEntity<User> adminOnly() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            User.builder().data("admin only page").build(),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/role")
@Secured({"ROLE_USER"})
ResponseEntity<User> user() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            User.builder().data("Hello World! I am role user.").build(),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

in junit.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users").with(user("u1").password("p1").roles("USER")))
            .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello World")));

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users/admin").with(user("u1").password("p1").roles("USER")))
            .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
}
```

I expect the 2nd test to be 403 but it returns 200.

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /users/admin
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = {}

Async:
Async started = false
 Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
         Type = null

ModelAndView:
    View name = null
         View = null
        Model = null

FlashMap:
   Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 200
Error message = null
      Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
 Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
         Body = {"data":"admin only page"}
Forwarded URL = null
Redirected URL = null
      Cookies = []
```

anything i'm missing?

I also tried to remove all the @Secured and replaced them with the following. still cannot get 403 in junit.

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/user").hasAnyRole("ROLE_USER")
            .antMatchers("/users/admin").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
```

using authorities does not work either. now it always returns 403.

in config.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/users/user").hasAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers("/users/admin").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("u1").password("p1").authorities("USER").and()
            .withUser("u2").password("p2").authorities("ADMIN", "ACTUATOR");
}
```

}

in junit.

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users/admin").with(user("u1").password("p1")
.authorities(Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")))))
            .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
```

Comment: You *probably* don't want to be mocking your calls out if you want to invoke real security.

Comment: then how would you recommend testing the security aspect? @Makoto

Comment: got the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675020/testing-security-in-spring-boot-1-4

Comment: Please make it an answer and accept it (make sure it's not a link-only answer)