# Spring MockMvc protecting public urls

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to unit test a controller class in my spring application. I am struggling a lot with this test. I want to test my my controller both in terms of method functionality and also authentication AND authorization.

Functionality is not an issue, but authorization and authentication are. Since I want to UNIT test I do not wish to annotate my test class with `@SpringBootTest` as this loads the entire application context (if I am not mistaken). So I decided to go with `@WebMvcTest` which adds security and my first issue with this is that it does not take roles into account. I have urls which are protected by roles and `@WebMvcTest` doesn't seem to care about them. Also, after testing all my secured URLs I decided to test my public urls and I wrote my tests without any validation which resulted in a 401 error. After this I realized that all my other tests were passing by coincidence as in fact all urls happened to be protected and not the ones I have set in my security config class.

After reading online I found that I can include my security config class as part of the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. The only issue with this is that the tests don't run as the application context cannot be loaded. The reason being that the the security config class contains some variables annotated with `@Autowired`. I started to include `@MockBean` and the respective bean in my test class and one by one the errors started to change until finally the application context was loaded. I don't like this as none of the examples I found online had to do this, and it seems dirty to just have random variables inside my test just to please the config class.

I am really stuck and have been searching for hours but nothing has worked for me. I simply want to test my endpoints for functionality, authorization, and authentication using my config class and not some default class that Spring uses.

However, I have a question which I'm unsure about and maybe someone more experienced can answer me. Does testing authorization and authentication go outside of the scope of unit testing? Do I need to load the entire application context using `@SpringBootTest` ?

This is a snippet of my test class with the annotations and how I prepare MockMvc:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = MyController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class,SecurityConfig.class})
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
}
```

My controller class is annotated with `@Restcontroller` and none of the methods have `@PreAuthorize` or `@PostAuthorize`, they simply rely on the security config file. When testing manually (making calls to the API via POSTMAN) everything works as it should so I'm certain its a test configuration issue from my part.

This is my security config class (snippet):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@Order(3)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private ClassA classA;
    @Autowired
    private ClassB classB;
    @Autowired
    private ClassC classC;


...

.antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll() 
}
```

This is the test that keeps returning 401 when I know it should return 200:

```
 @Test
    public void testGetIsProductionValue() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/public/production")
        .param("production", "false"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
      }
```

Comment: what else is in your snippet?

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6514 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675020/testing-security-in-spring-boot-1-4.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! After reading this I've come to the conclusion that to test security I will write a separate integration test.